# integrate spring security using data from database

Tags: database, spring, spring-security

I am developping an application with struts2, hibernate, and, spring.
I am trying to integrate spring security.
this is my springSecurity.xml :

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login/formLogin"
        default-target-url="/login/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/login/formLogin?login_error=1"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <security:logout />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="datasource"
         users-by-username-query=
        "select id, Rol_id, email, motDePasse from user u where u.email=?"
         authorities-by-username-query=
        "select u.email,r.role from user u, role r where u.Rol_id=r.id and u.email=?"
        />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

tables user and role:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `role` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`role` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Rol_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
`motDePasse` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `FK_Association_user_role` (`Rol_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

login.jsp

```
 <form name='loginForm'
    action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check"
    method='POST'>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
        value="${_csrf.token}" />

</form>
```

The problem is as follows:

even if I provide the correct username and password, I get "Bad credentials."
any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your queries are wrong, the `users-by-username-query` must return 3 fields representing the `username`, `password` and `enabled` which should be respectively a `String`, `String` and `boolean`. However you return more fields and apparently the 3rd isn't a `boolean`.

Comment: first of all, thanks for responding,
is that mean that my tables have to respect this schema?

Comment: sorry but I am a beginner with spring security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the SQL in  configuration is not correct.

'users-by-username-query' attribute should have the following SQL pattern

```
Select email, motDePasse, enabled from user where email= ?
```

If you don't have enabled column in your table, you may return true as below

```
Select email, motDePasse, 'true' from user where email= ?
```

'authorities-by-username-query' attribute should have the following SQL pattern

```
Select user.email, role.role from role join user on role.id=user.Rol_id where user.email=?
```

Comment: thank you! your answer was very useful.
now i want to get my user details and set this object as a session object.
I am using struts2 how can i do that

Comment: yes, I resolved the problem by following your answer

Comment: :) I would be happy if you vote up for my answer. The security details would be automatically available in your session if struts and spring security is configured correctly. I think you have configured it correctly otherwise it wouldn't have worked. Do you want to access the user details in your JSP or Action class?

Comment: Ok, i want to access ths user details in my action class

Comment: voting up requires 15 reputation i have just 3 :)

Comment: ha ha ha... thanks... hope the following link will be helpful to access user details from action class http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/how-do-i-obtain-security-details-jaas.html